# How to add a Mapinfo-style text halo in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Is there any way to imitate the Mapinfo halo (of something similar) in the Print Composer. I'm trying to put some text (copyright information) over the maps and I want to make it so that it is easier to read the text over the map.

I've tried using the "Background" option for the label, but this blocks out the entire label area, and not just what is printed (the text is being auto generated with a custom function).

I'm currently experimenting with text-shadow using the below HTML snippet, but the highlighting is too diffuse to make any clear difference

```
<span style= "color:red;text-shadow: 0 0 100px #ffffff;">[% printCopyRights()%]</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

These instructions from [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/) work just fine:

```
<p style="-webkit-text-stroke: 5px black; font-size:100; color:#fff;">QGIS</p>
```

[image]